# SpriteKit and UIKit compatibility: OpenGL error when migrating to Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, sprite-kit

I just don't understand what is going on since I migrated to Swift 2.
I have a Tabbed application and I am getting this error:

```
<CAEAGLLayer: 0x7fb2e053fb40>: calling -display has no effect.
Assertion failed: (length + offset <= _length), function commit_data, 
file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Jet_Sim/Jet-1.50/Jet/jet_types_OpenGL.h, line 863.
```

I know it is really vague but I don't know where to start looking for bugs.
Thanks.

**Edit:** 
I just realized it might be related to the fact that I am trying to embed a GameViewController into the TabbedController.
However, it did not cause any error before iOS 9.0.
Any clue?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem while trying to use SKShapeNode with a path. I created a new SpriteKit project in swift and I can reproduce it easily.  The stack trace varies so much that it hints that the memory is being corrupted badly. Are you using SKShapeNode?

Comment: Yes,  I am making very complex skshapenodes .  However, I have other apps that work perfectly fine even when using skshapenode

Comment: Thank you for you comment @FernandoMazzon. I solved the problem by reducing the number of vertices in my shapes :D

Comment: yes, I did that as well. Did you bother finding out what the hardcoded cap seems to be? For now i'm going to split my path in several shape nodes to overcome this limit.

Comment: No, sorry, I did not bother since many blogs recommend not to use SKShapeNode due to memory leakage etc. So I just accepted the fact that I should be very careful since I haven't found a replacement yet.

Comment: I know, but sadly there seems to be no better way of drawing a path and texturing it. I am using it to create pretty realistic lightning bolts. Aside from this, strokeShader support broke completely. Thankfully i was able to get the same effect though some tinkering on the texture with photoshop filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was with SKShapeNode. I was drawing ring portions with too many vertices. By decreasing the number of steps in the following function, the problem disappeared!!

```
func drawPortion2(r1:CGFloat, r2:CGFloat, angle1:CGFloat, angle2:CGFloat, fillColor:UIColor, steps:Int)->SKShapeNode{
let vertices=UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>.alloc(2*steps);
let stepsF=CGFloat(steps);

for j in 0..<steps{

    vertices[j]=CGPoint(x: r2*cos(angle2-CGFloat(j)*(angle2-angle1)/stepsF), y: r2*sin(angle2-CGFloat(j)*(angle2-angle1)/stepsF));

}

for j in 0..<steps {

    vertices[steps+j]=CGPoint(x: r1*cos(angle2-CGFloat(steps-j)*(angle2-angle1)/stepsF), y: r1*sin(angle2-CGFloat(steps-j)*(angle2-angle1)/stepsF));

}

let portion=SKShapeNode(points:vertices, count: 2*steps);
//portion.position=centerPos;
portion.fillColor=fillColor;

return portion;

}
```

Comment: Did you file a radar with Apple for this? The problems seems to be related to total vertices in a scene, rather than individual path complexity, but under Xcode 7.2/10.11 it still shows up.