# SpriteKit and programmatically draw simple graphics

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

Any suggestion on using SpriteKit rendering engine, but have the ability to draw game graphic programmatically. Those graphics are simple but slightly complex than just rectangular and oval.

I recently found out the `SKShapeNode` have a cap on the complexity when using custom path. I basically have a function that take a number to generate random `CGPath` shape, The larger the number the more complex and details about the shape. When I use a small number, there is no problem, but when I use a larger number to generate more complex path, `SKShapeNode` give me this error. (I tested on real device with iOS9.2.1 as well)

> Assertion failed: (length + offset <= _length)

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677503/spritekit-and-uikit-compatibility-opengl-error-when-migrating-to-swift-2)

Now I don't think using `SKShapeNode` is a good idea, so any suggestion on programmatically draw graphics that able to work nicely with SpriteKit?

I read somewhere else which is draw using the any graphics API available as long as it can convert to a format that `SKTexture` can initialize, is the right way to go?

Answer (score 1):

If you will use `SKTexture` you can draw your chart with `CGContext`.

First of all you need create array of chart's points like:

```
let pathPoints: [CGPoint] = [...]
```

Then you need to call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)` where `rect.size` is `CGSize` object which determines the size of the region in which will be inscribed the chart and `rect` is `CGRect` object. Next step is creation of `CGContextRef` and it setting:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth)
```

where `lineWidth` is `CGFloat` type value.

After this you can create your chart in context like this:

```
if pathPoints.count > 1 {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, pathPoints.first!.x, pathPoints.first!.y)
    for var i = 1; i < pathPoints.count; ++i {
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pathPoints[i].x, pathPoints[i].y)
    }
}
CGContextStrokePath(context)
```

Then you need to create image form context like this:

```
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

Then create texture form `image` and use it for `SKSpriteNode` object that will be added to the scene:

```
let pathTexture = SKTexture(image: image)
let pathNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: pathTexture)
pathNode.position = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.width/2 - lineWidth/2, rect.origin.y + rect.height/2 - lineWidth/2)
pathNode.zPosition = 0

someParrentNodeThatOnScene.addChild(pathNode)
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

That's all you need to create chart.